# Different versions of the operating system?

Tags: kubuntu, versions

The current version of Kubuntu is **20.04**.
In the opera browser when i open *about Opera* it appears to me that i have system : Ubuntu **20.04.1 LTS (x86_64; KDE)**.
Why does this version appear to me and to see what operating system you have outside of the system settings where you need to look ?
[image]

System up to date
[image]

os release
[image]

Comment: In system settings i have Kubuntu 20.04 ; system is up to date.

Comment: If you have been doing normal apt-update/upgrade and/or you have Unattended Upgrades enabled (it's enabled by default during install), then you have automatically migrated from 20.04 to 20.04.1. This is normal behavior for the vast majority of users.

Comment: In my system information appear Kubuntu 20.04 not Kubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Think system settings just give main version.  Opera gets a bit fancy, Firefox just gives version of firefox and it is on ubuntu with no version number.

Comment: As a conclusion the operating system is Kubuntu 20.04.1 .

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your 20.04.1 and to check the currently installed OS version you can use "lsb_release -a" command

Comment: @White Mars why doesn't the same version appear in system settings ?

Comment: Well in your case I am not really sure why this is happening. But this concludes that your currently installed OS version is 20.04.1. If you still which to investigate further try to look at "/etc/os-release" file. Try to update your system it might fix it automatically

Comment: @White Mars i updated the system and checked the os release file for the same result.

Comment: @White Mars your Kubuntu version is 20.04.1 in system settings?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.05 LTS but yes I get same result in both system settings and in os-release. I think this issue is caused because the file from which your gui system settings is picking up details is not updated, that's why you see 20.04, I myself don't know which is used by GUI system settings for details. There are many more ways to see OS version. You can read the following if you want : https://linuxhint.com/check_os_version_linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to see the operating system version is to hover over the username in the *Application Launcher*. I think that only main version 20.04 will appear in system settings even if the system is updated to next version 20.04.1 etc.